# Initialize a rotation matrix of dimension (n*n)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rotation

I have to initialize a rotation matrix for a given dimension (n), for eg n = 80

I know how to create a (2*2) or some small dimensions, but is there a shortcut to extend it to any given dimension n?

I have tried creating a (2 * 2) dimension rotation matrix

```
theta = np.radians(30)
cos_val, sin_val = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
rotation_matrix = np.array(((cos_val,-sin_val), (sin_val, cos_val)))
print(rotation_matrix) 

'''output:
[[ 0.8660254       -0.5      ]
[ 0.5             0.8660254]]'''
```

Looking for a way to intialize it to any given dimension n.

Comment: How do you mean to rotate for some given angle in, let's say, 3D? You need to have more rotation parameters. If you think just about rotating in the XY plane, you need to have that same matrix in top left corner, and matrix[3][3] to be equal to 1, other values should be 0.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386478/define-rotation-matrices-for-arbitrary-dimension

Comment: Thanks. This helps